# Get through vs finish

Tags: meaning, difference, quotations

Today my doubt is about the word “get through”. Basically the meaning is like “finish” something right? Well in this quote “when you get through the homework, I’ll give you more” can I use the word “finish” instead of “get through” for example “when you finish the homework, I’ll give you more”. If its possible replace this word, can you explain me when to use each one?

Answer (score 2):

### To get through (something) means to succeed or finish

> SUCCEED
>
> FINISH
>
> - I've got a stack of paperwork to **get through** before I can go out.
>
> -- [*Cambridge Dictionary*](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/get-through-sth)

The Cambridge dictionary does not describe this *phrasal verb* as informal, and says it is accepted in British English, American English and "business English".

You may have noticed that **to finish** sounds more precise.  If you want to sound precise, use "to finish".

> **Yes:** You **finish** a course of study.
>
> **Yes:** You **finish** a load of work.
>
> **Yes:** You **finish** a competition.
>
> **Yes:** You **finish** a race.

"Get through" brings with it a **metaphorical** image that suggests many obstacles, like getting through a **mountain of paperwork** or a difficult path through a jungle.  If you like this **shade of meaning**, use "to get through".

> ## To Finish:
>
> [image: Finish Line of a Race]
>
> ## To Get Through:
>
> [image: paperwork]
>   [image: jungle]
>   -- Photos: Aaron Logan ([Wikimedia](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Lightmatter_paperwork.jpg)), Duffy Thibaud ([Wikimedia](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:In_the_jungle.JPG) )

Examples:

> **Yes:** You **get through** a course of study.
>
> **Yes:** You **get through** a load of work.
>
> **Maybe:** You **get through** a competition.
>
> **Maybe:** You **get through** a race.

Generally, you don't say you "got through" a race, unless you mean to say that it was especially difficult or you are explaining that you had *hardships* that *other people doing the same race didn't have*.